# HDFS web interface alternative

Tags: eclipse, hadoop, eclipse-plugin, hdfs

Alright, this is annoying! I am new to Hadoop. And I am trying to find decent alternative to basic HDFS web interface. i tried with hadoop eclipse plugin but seems it's oudated already and it's pain to set it up correctly! I have cloudera's distribution installed and I heard about cloudera desktop but it's no longer available. Can anybody tell me decent alternative to HDFS web interface where I can download and upload files to HDFS via GUI easily? P.S I am running everything on my local no, cluster involved. Tried a lot to find , but nothing seems to be pointing towards right direction

Comment: Have you tried any of these?
http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/MountableHDFS

Comment: Yeah, this could be useful one, found this https://ccp.cloudera.com/display/CDHDOC/Mountable+HDFS to get this done, however still looking for Mac OS X installation of hadoop-fuse..couldn't find instructions there..Tried to install it via Mac port but failed..Error: Port hadoop-0.20-fuse not found

Comment: EDIT: Hadoop FUSE is not available for Mac OS X , thus mountable HDFS isn't the options for me!

Answer (score 0):

You can use webhdfs of which REST API supports the complete FileSystem interface for HDFS.  http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/webhdfs.html

OR

You can integrate hadoop with hoop(HDFS over HTTP), which is used to  access HDFS via HTTP protocol. Hoop provides access to all Hadoop Distributed File System (HDFS) operations (read and write) over HTTP/S

for more details please refer.
http://bigobject.blogspot.in/2013/03/hoop-https-over-hdfs.html

or also you can user HTTPFS as a option to Hoop

http://bigobject.blogspot.in/2013/03/apache-hadoop-httpfs-service-that.html

Comment: Thanks Amol, I went thorough this, However I am looking for GUI where I can make operations on HDDFS easily just like other application. Hoop's client seems to be not providing such GUI(correct me if I am wrong!)

Comment: For that purpose you can use webhdfs of which REST API supports the complete FileSystem interface for HDFS.  http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/webhdfs.html